# get unexpect datas from channel using goroutine

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

A piece of code from tutorials on [tour.golang.org](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(s []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range s {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    s := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c) //give 17
    go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c) //give -5
    x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

The output result is always `-5 17 12` which means the first goroutine is stably behind the second. As my understanding to multithreading and channel, the order of result should be the opposite in this simple context.When the goroutine's task become more complexed the order should be unexpectable.So how to explain this LIFO like issue?

Comment: run more times, it is unexpectable. though in most of time is `-5 17 12`, but it's absolutely not always.

Comment: @zzn I've run it hundreds of times using bash script.And it's stable.

Comment: i run less than ten times, and get `17 -5 12`

Comment: Did u get  any `-5 17 12`?

Comment: most of the output is `-5 17 12`, got one `17 -5 12`

Comment: After running a script I found on Mac its all `-5 17 12` and on Centos all is `17 -5 12`.Thats seems OS dependent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143386/discussion-between-young-and-zzn).